# How to vertically center an a tags text?

Tags: html, css

How do you vertically center an a tag's text?

http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/uypnI

Super basic example:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a>W</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}


div {
  float: left;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

a {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: papayawhip;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Comment: This doesn't work for the a tag alone. Are you saying I'd have to wrap it in a div?